# How to do Wiremock with actual running Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, wiremock

I want to deploy virtual service or wire mock service so which can be dynamically plugged in my application when external service down.

I want to configure Wire Mock in my Spring Boot application.

I have created bean MockServer class put code inside it so which will be starting mock server when application context is loaded
also added stubFor multiple URLs for which I want to get result from mock server.

Is it correct way to do this?

Do I need mock server restarted for every request?

I want service virtualization or wire mock to fake response for external service called in my application.

Ex. 
I have a app MyApp which is calling internally ExtApp to get some data.
Url MyApp/getData will call internally ExtApp/someData. 
Mock ExtData with MockServer so it will be returned with mock/stub data.

int PORT = 8090;
    WireMockServer wireMockServer = null;

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(
            WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig().port(PORT).extensions(new DynamicTransformer()));
    wireMockServer.start();

    configureFor("localhost", PORT);

    stubFor(get(urlPathMatching("/goalSummary/[^/]+/pin")).withHeader("accept", equalTo("application/json"))
            .willReturn(aResponse().withTransformers("dynamic-transformer")));

    stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/my/resource"))
            .willReturn(aResponse()
                .withStatus(200)
                .withBody("Some response for resource")));
}

public void reset() {

    wireMockServer.resetAll();
}

@PreDestroy
public void stop() {
    wireMockServer.stop();
}

public static class DynamicTransformer extends ResponseDefinitionTransformer {

    @Override
    public ResponseDefinition transform(Request request, ResponseDefinition responseDefinition, FileSource files,
            Parameters parameters) {
        String path = request.getUrl();
        String dynamicPath = "1111"; // Pull out the dynamic part
        String transformedJson = "{\"name\": \"Shyam\"}"; // Render the JSON
                                                            // string
                                                            // applicable
        return new ResponseDefinitionBuilder().withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").withStatus(200)
                .withBody(transformedJson).build();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "dynamic-transformer";
    }

}
```

It is correct way to do in application dynamically pick ExtApp or MockServer url?

Anything better approach to do these kind of scenarios?

Comment: It looks like a Dummy Service which deployed externally so any use in real application running.

Comment: It looks like a Dummy Service which deployed externally so any use in real application running. It seems there is no use of tomakehurst any one can create application and send response with dummy data. So how this virtual server is helping in specific scenarios?